# unable to read the splited lines after replacement

Tags: perl

My input:

```
mySql1 10,10,10 type  
mySql2 10,10,10 type
mySql3 10,10,10 type
```

I was trying to search the string mysql in my input file and want to split 
this way then I want to read split string line by line.

```
mySql 10
mySql 10
mySql 10
```

I am able to read the first split line "mysql 10", but i am missing 
next two lines.

What could be the problem with my code?

my code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $find ="mySql1 10,10,10 type";
my $replace ="\nmySql1 10\nmySql1 10\nmySql1 10 ";

while(<$fh>)
{
    if (/^mySql/)
    {
        s/$find/$replace/;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where does `$fh` come from? Because you use `strict` and `warnings` (thanks for that!) you must get some error. Not?

Comment: Your `$find` contains `mySql1` with a trailing `1` and thus won't catch the 2nd and 3rd line (because they only contain `mySql2` and `…3`).

Comment: $fh is the file handler for input file and the input file has multiple lines just i want to search line contain  mySql

Comment: let say line mysql1 10,10,10  which is match then i am reading first value but why i ma skipping rest of two values

Comment: Look at my comment above! You search for `mySql1` and that is only contained in your first line.

Comment: The past participle of "split" is just "split": there is no "splitted".

Answer (score -1):

**Script**

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
    s/^mySql(\d)    # the literal string 'mySql' followed by a digit.
                    # We capture that digit as $1.
      \s            # a space
      (\d+),        # digits (your '10'), followed by a ',', captured as $2
      \2,           # that very same digits again (i.e. again '10')
      \2            # once again
      \s            # a space
      type          # literal 'type'
      /mySql$1 $2\nmySql$1 $2\nmySql$1 $2\n/x;
    print;
}

__DATA__
mySql1 10,10,10 type
mySql2 10,10,10 type
mySql3 10,10,10 type
```

**Output**

```
mySql1 10
mySql1 10
mySql1 10

mySql2 10
mySql2 10
mySql2 10

mySql3 10
mySql3 10
mySql3 10
```

**Explanation**

I added the `/x` switch to the `s///` command. It allows for
comments and such in the find-pattern. I explained the regex
in the code above.

The replacement is simply three times `mySql$1 $2\n`. `$1` is the
content of the first capture group (your digits 1, 2, 3), and
`$2` is the content of the second capture group (your 10).

Note that this will work only for your exact input. It will *not* catch any of the following:

```
mySql4 11,12,13 type      # different numbers
mySql5 10,10,10,10 type   # not three numbers (but four)
mySql10 10,10,10 type     # two digits after 'mySql'
```

But that was how you specified your question.

Comment: if the input is mySqul1{3}   {10,10,10} type this word work ..?

Comment: Of course not. The different input needs a different pattern.

Comment: Any suggestions what would be the change if the input is mySqul1{3} {10,10,10} ?

Comment: your code is doing matching and replacement in the same line but what i was doing in first matching then substitution in different line as while loop read file line by line so i am able to read only first line my understating is correct ?

Comment: You can drop the `if (/^mySql/)` because the following replacement will do nothing if the search string isn't found. Your code is "if the line starts with 'mySql' then replace lines starting with 'mySql' with …". My code just skips the first check because it is unnecessary.

Comment: For your now different input you can try this: `s/^mySq(u?)l(\d)\{3\} \{(\d+),\3,\3\} type/"mySq${1}l$2 $3\n" x 3/e;`. I didn't test it and I also do not know what your expected output is.

Comment: @expecting the same output but with different input type is "mySql1{3} {10,10,10} " .

Comment: Now you again changed your input. The word `type` is missing and suddenly the `u` in `mySqul` disappeared. Programming is about precision. Please be more careful when asking questions here. The people answering here are doing this in their spare time and for free. We don't like guesswork and moving targets. I answered your original question according to your specification. If you have another question, feel free to post it.

Comment: @PerlDuck: You've allowed a dialogue to continue far too long without explaining the "one question, optional enhancements" model. Any "yes, but" comments should be directed to a new question.